# On the Syntactic Mapping of Transparent Identifiers in LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following query expression:

```
var result1 =
    from coef in inputs
    let negB = -coef.b
    let discriminant = coef.b * coef.b - 4 * coef.a * coef.c
    let twoA = 2 * coef.a
    select new
    {
        FirstRoot = (negB + discriminant) / twoA,
        SecondRoot = (negB - discriminant) / twoA
    };
```

As an exercise, I attempted to manually apply the syntactic mapping to regular method calls that the compiler applies. I came up with the following code:

```
var result2 =
    inputs.Select(coef => new
    {
        negB = -coef.b,
        discriminant = coef.b * coef.b - 4 * coef.a * coef.c,
        twoA = 2 * coef.a
    })
    .Select(transparentIdentifier => new
    {
        FirstRoot = (transparentIdentifier.negB + transparentIdentifier.discriminant) / transparentIdentifier.twoA,
        SecondRoot = (transparentIdentifier.negB - transparentIdentifier.discriminant) / transparentIdentifier.twoA
    });
```

The results are appealingly the same and all is well. It occured to me, however, that the query expression could also be translated to something like this:

```
var result3 =
    inputs.Select(coef => new { coef, negB = -coef.b })
        .Select(tp1 => new { tp = tp1, discriminant = tp1.coef.b * tp1.coef.b - 4 * tp1.coef.a * tp1.coef.c })
        .Select(tp2 => new { tp1 = tp2, twoA = 2 * tp2.tp.coef.a })
        .Select(tp3 => new
        {
            FirstRoot = (tp3.tp1.tp.negB + tp3.tp1.discriminant) / tp3.twoA,
            SecondRoot = (tp3.tp1.tp.negB - tp3.tp1.discriminant) / tp3.twoA
        });
```

Having loaded dotPeek and had a *peek* (hurr hurr), I learned that this is actually how the compiler applies the syntactic mapping (more or less).

Is there a particular reason for this? I suspect that this is probably done at the convince of the compiler but having learned about degenerate query expressions, I wonder if there is anything more to the story here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few reasons for this:

1. Depending on the LINQ provider **user code can tell the difference** between the two forms. This can be an externally detectable change. It is possible to use user-defined methods for things like `where`. It is not required to use `Enumerable.Where`. The same goes for select/let. So you could easily write yourself some extension methods that allow you to detect the difference. This violates the as-if rule (if the C# spec guarantees a certain translation which I don't know).
2. The expressions that you compute in that sequence of let's are independent but they could also form an arbitrary DAG of dependencies. One explanation for this inefficient compilation would be that the compiler team has **not implemented** the necessary dependency analysis. Without tracking the dependency graph properly they cannot optimize this code. This might be a case of "not implemented".

For LINQ to objects (i.e. using `Enumerable.*` methods) the compiler could be hard-wired to fold any sequence of `Select` calls into one. User code could not possibly detect the difference. So this is just not implemented.